# MySQLi not retrieving the first row

Tags: mysqli

MySQLi not returning first row

```
$query = mysqli_query($Connection, "SELECT * FROM `counter`");
while($Counter = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
$Counter['id'];
}
```

it starts returning from the second id, I don't see the problem with it. Even without the loop it still returns the second id first

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the results returned do include all of the records in the table (it should) try adding an `ORDER BY id` clause to your query, the default ordering is ASC I believe.

If the id column is the tables primary key (your question doesn't state the table schema) I would have thought it should be doing this by default but I am not sure about that tbh!

HTH

Comment: Also if you need only the first row, then `LIMIT 1` can also be used in the mysql query

Comment: Nop, the result isn't returning all that's why I very confused with it

Comment: can you provide the code you have within the while loop, also, have you tried dumping the returned results such as `print_r(mysqli_fetch_array($query))` if so what were the results? I would guess at this stage that you might be loosing the result somewhere rather than it not being returned.

Comment: Solved the problem, I accidentally used the first row for result check